# Superfish menu spacing and dropdowns

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, superfish

Ive been asked to make some changes to the menu of website. Trouble is, I'm having a problem with the way the superfish menu works, specifically the drop down turns off before I get to the sub menus.I guessing its a css issue and that whatever triggers the dropdowns is being compromised by something I have changed.

I would be grateful if someone with a bit of experience can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. Link is: http://www.gordoncastlehighlandgames.co.uk/wp/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Look in your css: The line-height of the a (the parent link) is 28px but the top pos of the ul:hover is 32px, change that to 28px or the other to 32px: http://www.gordoncastlehighlandgames.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/gchg/stylesheet/superfish.css?ver=3.8 -- also look and see that you have a double bracket on the last line. Check your css for errors like that and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's hard to tell, but my guess is that there is a small gap between your top level menu and the drop-down menu causing the cursor to effectively de-select the menu before you get to it. Reduce this margin/gap and that should solve the problem.

If not, please post your code or a jsfiddle and I will update

***Update***

Found the problem. In your style.css, you have the line `div.sixteen.columns.mt0 {margin-top: -20px;}`. This negative margin is overlapping the top navigation causing the odd behaviour. Remove this negative margin (set it to "`0`") and the navigation will work again.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time to respond. Ive put all the relevant code in a pastbin (no idea how to use jsfiddle!) Hope this is OK.

http://pastebin.com/EJefKp1L

Comment: This is the reason why: Look in your css: The line-height of the a (the parent link) is 28px but the top pos of the ul:hover is 32px, change that to 28px or the other to 32px: gordoncastlehighlandgames.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/gchg/… -- also look and see that you have a double bracket on the last line. Check your css for errors like that and others. – cab 34 secs ago edit

Comment: Hi,

Unless I misunderstood I didn't work..

Comment: Found the problem. In your style.css, you have the line `div.sixteen.columns.mt0 {margin-top: -20px;}`. This negative margin is overlapping the top navigation causing the odd behaviour. Remove this negative margin (set it to "0") and the navigation will work again.

Comment: ALSO, you have a blank H1 tag within `<div class="sixteen columns mt0">` - unless you plan on actually using this, you should remove it. This div is what was overlapping the menu

Comment: Ah! Thank Wickywills! Trouble is, now I need to find out how to close up that gap at the top of the slideshow..

Comment: Please see the comment I just added - you have a blank div with a blank h1. Doesn't look like this is needed, and it will be what is causing your problems :)

Comment: Just saw that after I posted - the initial response. Thanks pal - owe you a drink.

Comment: No worries! I only drink water, but if you must, make it a mineral water :)
Also, would you be able to mark the answer as 'accepted'?

Comment: A glass of Highland Springwater it is then. Cheers!